# Code explanation for a While Loop within a For Loop

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, while-loop

Can anyone explain to me why the output for the program below, if you input the values: 5, 222, 2043, 29, 2, 20035 is 22222? I'm trying to solve it on paper and I just can't get to this result.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int n=0;
int x=0;
int s=0;
int i=1;


int main() {
    cin >> n;
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        cin >> x;
        int nr=1;
        while(x>9) {
            nr=nr*10;
            x=x/10;
        }
        s=s+x*nr;
    }
    cout << s;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, given `x`, what do you end up with for `x*nr`?

Comment: Step through the debugger?

Comment: You know you can step through the code with your debugger and see what each step is doing.  It is a very useful tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your while loop divides x by 10 every time. And since you're dealing with integers, that just shifts the decimal number one to the right: `7234 -> 723`. 
It does this untill it is smaller than 10, or in other words, there is one (the first) digit left: 7. Then it multiplies again by 10^(times divided by 10): 7000.
This means the code whitin your for-loop makes all but the first digits zero in each x. so in the end you'll have: `200 + 2000 + 20 + 2 + 20000`